# Paginating a JSF forEach control

Tags: java, jsf

I just had to switch from ICEFaces dataTable to *simple* forEach tag, because I had to place elements in two rows rather than 1.

Anyway, now I can't use the old paginator because it returns me an error. I know I can use *begin* and *end* attributes to define from and to what element should forEach iterate, but still I don't know how to get it all together.

I currently have something very very simple like

```
<table>
    <c:forEach id="content" items="#{bean.collection}" var="item">
    [two well-formatted TRs]
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Do you have already-done examples on how to paginate with simple first/forward/back/last buttons this table? I don't need directly clicking on page number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c:forEach` has a `begin` and `end` attribute (see [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html)), with them you can easily create pagination. You will need to have a `begin`, `end`, and `listSize` attribute in your bean.

Create a first, back link if `begin==0`; create forward, last link if `end<listSize`. In the bean set begin and end according to the current page.

If you need numbers in pagination, it is possible too, see:

http://blog.opencampaign.co.uk/index.php/2010/07/pagination-using-only-jstl.html and
http://www.coderanch.com/t/60467/oa/do-database-pagination-JSTL-tags